# HTML Form from free template website not sending emails and showing an error message

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

I'm learning to code basic websites and I'm having trouble getting the contact form to work. I'm using this free template: https://themewagon.com/themes/free-bootstrap-4-html5-construction-company-website-template-builderz/ and uploaded it to a shared host that I purchased.

From what I gather, the contact form works with 4 files: The HTML contact form, a contact.php file (where i should put the email where i want to receive the messages) a contact.js file and a jqBootstrapValidation.min.js file which I understand help with the validation of the data.

This is the code for these files:

**HTML Form:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="contact-form">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />
                <p class="help-block text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
                <p class="help-block text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="How can we help?" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a subject" />
                <p class="help-block text-"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text"></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn" type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      http_response_code(500);
      exit();
    }

    $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $m_subject = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']));
    $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

    $to = "myemail@mail.com"; // Change this email to yours //
    $subject = "$m_subject:  $name";
    $body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\n\nEmail: $email\n\nSubject: $m_subject\n\nMessage: $message";
    $header = "From: $email";
    $header .= "Reply-To: $email";  

    if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $header))
      http_response_code(500);
?>
```

**contact.js**

```
$(function () {

    $("#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
        },
        submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var subject = $("input#subject").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();

            $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
            $this.prop("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: "contact.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    subject: subject,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append('</div>');
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + name + ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.prop("disabled", false);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        },
        filter: function () {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

$('#name').focus(function () {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

I changed the email in the contact.php file to my personal email and the custom one I created with the host I purchased, but when I try to run the form in the live website I always get the error "Sorry " + name + ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"

I looked at a couple of other similar threads where the issue got solved checking the opening and closing of the php file, I also tried to change the $to variable in the contact.php file to $email_to since I saw that in another post but it also didn't work.

I'm a bit lost here and would really appreciate any clues!

Comment: As a first step in debugging things perhaps you can create a really simple mail script that has hard-coded parameters ( check the php manual for syntax if needed )  and run that. If that basic email does not get delivered then you'll know the problem is with the host.  Look in the console and inspect the network request - are there errors with the ajax request ?

Answer (score -1):

SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol)

```
// Import the PHPMailer library
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

// Create a new PHPMailer object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// Configure the SMTP server
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server address
$mail->Port = 587; // SMTP server port number
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Encryption type (ssl or tls)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'your_email_address@gmail.com'; // Your email address
$mail->Password = 'your_password'; // Your email password

// Configure the email message
$mail->setFrom('your_email_address@gmail.com', 'Your Name'); // Sender email address and name
$mail->addAddress('recipient@example.com', 'Recipient Name'); // Recipient email address and name
$mail->Subject = 'Test email message'; // Email subject
$mail->Body = 'Hi, this is a test email message.'; // Email body

// Send the email message
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Failed to send email message.';
    echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Email message has been sent.';
}
```

[More about SMTP](https://zyrex.eu/formularz-kontaktowy-i-smtp/)